# Почему пузырьковая сортировка идет не до конца?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть массив из 4 элементов.Делаю пузырькову сортировку но последний шаг он не делает.
Вот код

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int []a = new int[10];
       a[0]=18;
       a[1]=7;
       a[2]=62;
       a[3]=1;
      SOrting sOrting = new SOrting();
      for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
          System.out.print("Before srotnig " + a[i] + " ");
      }
      sOrting.bubbleSort(a);

        for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
          System.out.print("  After srotnig " + a[i] + " ");
      }
    }


//--------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Вот класс сортировки

```
public class SOrting {

       public  void  bubbleSort(int a[]) {
        int out, in;
        int nElems=4;
        for (out = nElems - 1; out > 1; out--) // Внешний цикл (обратный)
        {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) // Внутренний цикл (прямой)
            {
                if (a[in] > a[in + 1]) // Порядок нарушен?
                {
                    swap(in, in + 1,a); // Поменять местами
                }
            }
        }
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------

    private void swap(int one, int two,int a[]) {
        long temp = a[one];
        a[one] = a[two];
        a[two] = (int) temp;
    }


}
```

Вот что получаю на выходе 
ДО сортировки

```
18 7 62 1
```

после сортировки

```
 7 1 18 62
```

почему `7 и 1` не меняются местами???я сделал все поформуле книжки . если сделать out>0 тогда будет `1 7` Но это неправильно у меня 4 элемента.ПОчему так ?

Comment: простите, а что вы делаете? кидайте числа в коллекцию или массив и дергайте `sort()`. Числа рассортируются по возрастанию (и не только)

Comment: Ну так вы массив просматриваете от `nElems - 1` до 1, т.е. по факту от 3 до 1 элемента массива. А нужно от 3 до 0-го. Поэтому out>0 будет правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что ваш внешний цикл заканчивается раньше, чем отсортирует элементы "1" и "7".
Измените условие внешнего цикла в вашем классе сортировки на следующее : (out = nElems - 1; **out > 0**; out--)

```
public class SOrting {
       public  void  bubbleSort(int a[]) {
        int out, in;
        int nElems=4;
        for (out = nElems - 1; out > 0; out--) // Внешний цикл (обратный)
        {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) // Внутренний цикл (прямой)
            {
                if (a[in] > a[in + 1]) // Порядок нарушен?
                {
                    swap(in, in + 1,a); // Поменять местами
                }
            }
        }
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------

    private void swap(int one, int two,int a[]) {
        long temp = a[one];
        a[one] = a[two];
        a[two] = (int) temp;
    }


}
```